# System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "X" to type 'Double' is not valid.'

Tags: vb.net

So basically when i used player1Score = player1Score + 1 and lblP1ScoreNumber.Text = player1Score it worked but it added one to both of the players score instead of just whoever won so i tried using an if statement to say "if whosTurn = x  Player1Score = Player1Score + 1   lblP1ScoreNumber.Text = Player1Score             ElseIf WhosTurn = 0 Then                 Player2Score = Player2Score + 1                 lblP2ScoreNumber.Text = Player2Score             End If" but then the error message that is in the title popped up at this line"ElseIf WhosTurn = 0 Then" any ideas? ( this is the error message"System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "X" to type 'Double' is not valid.' FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.")                                                                                                                                 Ill add the code again here so its a bit easier too see both the erroe message and the full code i have so far:              I tried what i said in the details of the problem                                                                                                     Public Class Form1

```
 Dim Board(8) As String
Dim Player1 As String = "X"
Dim Player2 As String = "O"
Dim XScore As String = ""
Dim WhosTurn As String = Player1
Dim Player1Score As Integer
Dim Player2Score As Integer
Public Property X As String

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ResetBoard()
End Sub

Private Sub ResetBoard()
    WhosTurn = Player1
    For i = 0 To 8
        Board(i) = ""
    Next
    If WhosTurn = Player1 Then
        lblPlayerTurn.Text = "It is player one's turn"
    ElseIf WhosTurn <> Player1 Then
        End
    End If

    lblScorePlayer1X.Text = "Player 1 score"
    lblPlayer2O.Text = "Player 2 score"

    'If WhosTurn = Player1 Then
    'lblPlayerTurn.Text = "It is player one's turn"
    'ElseIf WhosTurn = Player2 Then
    'lblPlayerTurn.Text = "It is player two's turn"
    'End If
    Button1.Text = ""
    Button2.Text = ""
    Button3.Text = ""
    Button4.Text = ""
    Button5.Text = ""
    Button6.Text = ""
    Button7.Text = ""
    Button8.Text = ""
    Button9.Text = ""

End Sub

Private Function CheckForWin(ByRef PlayerToCheck As String) As Boolean



    'Player1 wins
    If (Board(0) = PlayerToCheck And Board(3) = PlayerToCheck And Board(6) = PlayerToCheck) Then
        Return True
    ElseIf (Board(1) = PlayerToCheck And Board(4) = PlayerToCheck And Board(7) = PlayerToCheck) Then
        Return True
    ElseIf (Board(2) = PlayerToCheck And Board(5) = PlayerToCheck And Board(8) = PlayerToCheck) Then
        Return True
    ElseIf (Board(0) = PlayerToCheck And Board(1) = PlayerToCheck And Board(2) = PlayerToCheck) Then
        Return True
    ElseIf (Board(3) = PlayerToCheck And Board(4) = PlayerToCheck And Board(5) = PlayerToCheck) Then
        Return True
    ElseIf (Board(6) = PlayerToCheck And Board(7) = PlayerToCheck And Board(8) = PlayerToCheck) Then
        Return True
    ElseIf (Board(0) = PlayerToCheck And Board(4) = PlayerToCheck And Board(8) = PlayerToCheck) Then
        Return True
    ElseIf (Board(2) = PlayerToCheck And Board(4) = PlayerToCheck And Board(6) = PlayerToCheck) Then
        Return True
    End If

    Return False




End Function





Private Sub TakeTurn(ByVal Position As Integer)


    If (WhosTurn = Player1) Then
        Board(Position) = Player1
    Else
        Board(Position) = Player2

    End If
    'Check for win is here if you get confused 
    If (CheckForWin(WhosTurn) = True) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Player " & WhosTurn & " Won")

        If WhosTurn = "X" Then
            Player1Score = Player1Score + 1
            lblP1ScoreNumber.Text = Player1Score
        ElseIf WhosTurn = "O" Then
            Player2Score = Player2Score + 1
            lblP2ScoreNumber.Text = Player2Score
        End If

        ResetBoard()

        Return
        End If

        If (WhosTurn = Player1) Then

        WhosTurn = Player2
    Else

        WhosTurn = Player1
    End If

    If WhosTurn = Player2 Then
        lblPlayerTurn.Text = "It is player two's turn"
    ElseIf WhosTurn = Player1 Then
        lblPlayerTurn.Text = "It is player one's turn"
    End If
    'You've got that code wired to the label's on click event. Is that intended?
    'Shouldn 't it be at the bottom of the TakeTurn sub? Looks almost like you could replace 
    'that If statement and just set the label directly there instead of WhosTurn 
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Board(0) <> "" Then
        Return
    End If
    Button1.Text = WhosTurn
    TakeTurn(0)

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If Board(1) <> "" Then
        Return
    End If
    Button2.Text = WhosTurn
    TakeTurn(1)
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    If Board(2) <> "" Then
        Return
    End If
    Button3.Text = WhosTurn
    TakeTurn(2)
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    If Board(3) <> "" Then
        Return
    End If
    Button4.Text = WhosTurn
    TakeTurn(3)
End Sub

Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    If Board(4) <> "" Then
        Return
    End If
    Button5.Text = WhosTurn
    TakeTurn(4)
End Sub

Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    If Board(5) <> "" Then
        Return
    End If
    Button6.Text = WhosTurn
    TakeTurn(5)
End Sub

Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
    If Board(6) <> "" Then
        Return
    End If
    Button7.Text = WhosTurn
    TakeTurn(6)
End Sub

Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
    If Board(7) <> "" Then
        Return
    End If
    Button8.Text = WhosTurn
    TakeTurn(7)
End Sub

Private Sub Button9_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button9.Click
    If Board(8) <> "" Then
        Return
    End If
    Button9.Text = WhosTurn
    TakeTurn(8)
End Sub

Private Sub LabelTurn()

    If WhosTurn = Player1 Then
        lblPlayerTurn.Text = Player1
    Else
        lblPlayerTurn.Text = Player2
    End If


End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: lblP1ScoreNumber.Text is a string variable, Player1Score is an integer.  You have cast the Player1Score variable to a String.  Heaps of ways to do this, but the simplest is lblP1ScoreNumber.Text = Player1Score.ToString().  Also as per other question, it will be well worth your time reading up on Option Strict to avoid unintended type casting like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement

Comment: @Hursey thanks i have it working now ill add the working code now